# internal mod_rewrite leads to infinite redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, ngrok

I have a server on `localhost:8080` and I've piped requests to it via a tunneling software called `ngrok` so now ***I want to setup my mod_rewrite policy to map and serve any request from `mysubdomain.ngrok.com` to `localhost:8080` without redirecting the browser***.

```
# Turn on rewrites
RewriteEngine on
###
## Rules for "mysubdomain.ngrok.com"
###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysubdomain.ngrok.com$
RewriteRule .? %{REQUEST_URI} [L]
###
## Rules for "localhost:8080"
###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost:8080$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/prestashop/]
RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But I end up in infinite redirect loop! **What's the best way to** avoid this and **accomplish my goal**?

```
[/initial] [perdir /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/] add path info postfix: /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/api -> /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/api/products
[/initial] [perdir /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/api/products -> api/products
[/initial] [perdir /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/] applying pattern '.?' to uri 'api/products'
[/initial] [perdir /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/] RewriteCond: input='mysubdomain.ngrok.com' pattern='^mysubdomain.ngrok.com$' => matched
[/initial] [perdir /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/] rewrite 'api/products' -> '/prestashop/api/products'
[/initial] [perdir /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/] internal redirect with /prestashop/api/products [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[/initial/redir#1] [perdir /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/] add path info postfix: /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/api -> /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/api/products
[/initial/redir#1] [perdir /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/api/products -> api/products
[/initial/redir#1] [perdir /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/] applying pattern '.?' to uri 'api/products'
[/initial/redir#1] [perdir /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/] RewriteCond: input='mysubdomain.ngrok.com' pattern='^mysubdomain.ngrok.com$' => matched
[/initial/redir#1] [perdir /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/] rewrite 'api/products' -> '/prestashop/api/products'
[/initial/redir#1] [perdir /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/] internal redirect with /prestashop/api/products [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
...
[/initial/redir#10] [perdir /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/] add path info postfix: /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/api -> /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/api/products
[/initial/redir#10] [perdir /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/api/products -> api/products
[/initial/redir#10] [perdir /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/] applying pattern '.?' to uri 'api/products'
[/initial/redir#10] [perdir /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/] RewriteCond: input='mysubdomain.ngrok.com' pattern='^mysubdomain.ngrok.com$' => matched
[/initial/redir#10] [perdir /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/] rewrite 'api/products' -> '/prestashop/api/products'
[/initial/redir#10] [perdir /Users/root/dev/bitnami-ps1/apps/prestashop/htdocs/] internal redirect with /prestashop/api/products [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at logs and rules I can see that this rule is causing infinite looping:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysubdomain.ngrok.com$
RewriteRule .? %{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

As it is unconditionally writing a URI to itself for domain=`mysubdomain.ngrok.com`

Just comment it out and looping will be fixed.

Comment: That rule is incorrect, I admit, but what I'm asking is how to correct it to accomplish my goal.

Comment: As I suggested **Just comment it out** since this rule is not doing anything OR not doing what you have in mind. If you clarify what you intend to do using this rule I can suggest something.

Comment: I want to setup my mod_rewrite policy to map and serve any request from mysubdomain.ngrok.com to localhost:8080 without redirecting the browser.

Comment: What URL you want to show in browser localhost or mysubdomain? Also do you have control of server config on both sides?

Comment: In browser, i want to show mysubdomain.ngrok.com:80, I have control of the localhost:8080 apache server.

Comment: If you want to show `http://mysubdomain.ngrok.com` in browser then you need to have control of `mysubdomain.ngrok.com` Apache config to setup this proxy.